# Apache (2) throws "No such file or directory: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/fst.cgi' failed"

Tags: apache2, cgi

I am working in Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat) and running my [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) script under [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server), but it is showing me the following error...

> [Sat errorNo such file or directory: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/fst.cgi' failed
>   [Sat Oct 22 02:56:45 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: fst.cgi

My script is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print "hello world";
```

I have set the permissions of the file...

I have also added the following line in file `apache.conf`:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin/>
   Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

But still it is showing me the same error. I have done all the possible changes, but I didn't get any success...

Comment: Are you sure your script should not start with `#!/usr/bin/perl`?

Comment: no my script start with #!usr/bin/perl..

Comment: I think, the problem is in script header: try `#!/usr/bin/perl`.

Comment: I have also try this....but it showing me same error....

Comment: Similar happened to me after upgrading php - when I was removing old PHP it somehow also removed php-cgi, so I just reinstalled it `sudo apt install php-cgi`

Answer (score 42):

I encountered the same error found in my /var/log/apache2/error_log.
I finally realized that the Perl script was directly copied from my Windows system (via Parallels virtual machine) and it seems that the Windows' carriage return "\r\n" causes this error.

When I FTP this Perl script from Windows to Mac using ASCII mode
to automatically convert "\r\n" into "\r",
the same Perl script works correctly without any modification.

Comment: Here is a Perl script to convert the text files between Windows and Mac without using FTP: http://web.ntnu.edu.tw/~samtseng/tools/dos2mac.pl. To know how to use, just type: "perl -s dos2mac.pl"

Comment: +1 thank you, I was caught by this. I used `dos2unix` to correct line endings on my ubuntu machine.

Comment: Same issue and same solution by dos2unix with a Python3 script edited in Windows and ported to Linux for execution.

Answer (score 17):

The error message "No such file or directory" doesn't come from Apache nor from Perl. When Apache is invoking the script, it passes the execution to the command line interpreter (CLI) of the system. This CLI opens the script file and reads the first line "#!/usr/bin/perl" (shebang line).

As Sam Tseng has elaborated, the file obviously contains a Windows line break character sequence: "**\r**\n" (hexcode: x0D x0A, symbols: CR LF). Now the CLI interpreter reads the line until the "\n" character. The CLI doesn't recognice the "\r" character, so it becomes part of the path "/usr/bin/perl **\r**" and is not anymore part of the line break.

**Why does the option '-w' fix this issue?**

When you add the option '-w' than the character '\r' becommes part of the argument "-w\r". The path to the Perl executable can now be found "/usr/bin/perl" and "-w\r" is passed as command line argument. However, Perl is nice and doesn't cause errors when handling the "-w\r" option.

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same problem several times - try to modify your shebang in the file to:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

Now why this makes the script execute, beats me ... if you find out please let us know also.

Comment: This has saved me LITERALLY 12 times today. SOOO strange but it works! Just.. ugh.. peminds me why I do PHP instead :p

Comment: Worked for me, too, but see Sam Tseng's answer. The real reason was becuase my script used DOS line endings on a Linux machine. The '-w' seems to make PERL more leniant about line endings. From `--help` it says: `-w enable many useful warnings`.

Comment: Write it down and you will see what happens: "#!/usr/bin/perl -w\r" The '\r' character of the windows line break sequence "\r\n" disattaches from the path "/usr/bin/perl" and becomes part of the argument "-w\r". Now the system can find the perl executable and passes "-w\r" as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the "Windows' carriage return" which is produced when files are created inside a Windows environment.

this can be easily done by the command

```
dos2unix fst.cgi fst.cgi
```

The first fst.cgi is the file you want to convert and the second is the destination file name, which can remain the same.

Next step is to run the command

```
 chmod 755 fst.cgi
```

This will override the permission of the file and allow you to execute the file.

Good  luck

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a Similar error : (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/aaa.py' failed. And answers like Above can not be resolved.Then I find that : vim aaa.py `:set ff` and the fileformat is dos. `:set ff=unix` and wq soon fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your script executes OK under apache user: `# su -c /usr/lib/cgi-bin/fst.cgi apache`
- Make sure the directory `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` has 755 permission
- Make sure the script `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/fst.cgi` has 755 permission

Answer (score 0):

The same problem costs me almost a whole day! I would like to provide a possibility.

Both my PC and remote server OS is **Ubuntu 16.04**. And I am using [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) to transfer files from the PC to the remote server. The *default transfer type* is set as **Auto** which is the reason in my case.

The solution is that set the *default transfer type* as **Binary**. And the navigation path is: 
**Edit** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings** -> **Transfers** -> **File Types** -> **Default transfer type:**

Comment: I was surprised to learn today that Git automagically replaces LF with CRLF unless you set global settings or local .gitattributes files to override that behavior.  It didn't solve my problem but it's another use case.