# how to run python cgi script in ubuntu using xampp

Tags: python, ubuntu, xampp, cgi

I am not able to run python cgi script in ubuntu using xampp

## I have made necessary changes in httpd.conf(/opt/lampp/etc)

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

==========================================================

## and my python script file is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()    
print "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
print "Hello World!"
```

===========================================================

Thanks in advance !

Comment: After I run , get error as  "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
End of script output before headers: labels.py"

Comment: In the Python script deployed on the server, is there a line break between the 2nd and 3rd print statement?

Answer (score 1):

> The output of a CGI script should consist of two sections, separated
>   by a blank line. The first section contains a number of headers,
>   telling the client what kind of data is following.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html

In your current code example the blank line is missing (not in your originally posted code). Try changing the first `print` statement to:

`print "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\n`"

and it should work (at least it did on a Amazon server with Ubuntu and Apache).

My personal troubleshooting workflow with Python and cgi:

- Check the permissions of the script, e.g. is it owned by www-data?
- Does the Python script run when called from the command line? i.e. no simple typos, indentation errors, etc.
- Try using a logger (since you cannot `print` to `stdout`) to see where and when it crashes, e.g. this one: http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2011/08/14/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-logger-in-python/

Comment: I get error in error.log as      
[Tue May 17 11:54:24.307673 2016] [cgid:error] [pid 15122:tid 140289761994624] (2)No such file or directory: AH01241: exec of '/var/www/html/test/labels.py' failed
[Tue May 17 11:54:24.307933 2016] [cgid:error] [pid 15020:tid 140289461118720] [client 127.0.0.1:60209] End of script output before headers: labels.py

Comment: In your httpd.conf your cgi directory is "/opt/lampp/htdocs" but the Python script seems to be in  '/var/www/html/test/labels.py'. Does it work when you move the script or change http.conf?

Comment: And get ideas from site https://www.linux.com/blog/configuring-apache2-run-python-scripts

Comment: Can you post your http.conf entry?

Comment: ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html

 <Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
 <Directory /var/www/html/test>
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
 <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>

Comment: config file is 000-default.conf(/etc/apache2/sites-available)

Comment: owner of your python script is www-data?

Comment: finally i got clue from first option of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7914384/3898339

Comment: is your script executable? i.e. can you call it from the command line?