# Serving up Python CGI files on a Synology NAS

Tags: python, apache, synology

I cannot get python files to be served up with Apache 2.2 or 2.4 without a 500 error. I have WebStation installed, python, perl, php, and Apache 2.2 and 2.4 installed.

I can serve up static files just fine with apache. When I try to serve up a most basic "hello world" cgi, I get a 500 error. The error is

[cgid:error] [pid 10076:tid 140542621480832] (2)No such file or directory: AH01241: exec of  ['/volume2/Development/WebRepo/cgi-bin/test.py' failed.

Tried to execute both a perl script and a python script. Both run successfully from a command line, but not from served up with Apache (same errors of "no such file..") Also note this is a 500 error, not a 404, so it's seeing the file. I can serve up static HTML files just fine.

The python script couldn't be simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello, World.";
```

All files have 755 permissions.  The path to python is correct. I'm at a loss as to what to do next.

Comment: Not much of an Apache user but once that I used it my files had correct permissions etc, but one of the folders didn't. Did you happen to check that too? Edit: this seems related too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7858987/6655150

Answer (score 2):

Python can serve CGI scripts out of the box, using [`http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler).

On my Synology NAS I have official Python3 package installed (version 3.8.2-0150).
I can SSH into NAS as `admin` and add a script:

```
mkdir -p app/cgi-bin

cat << EOF > app/cgi-bin/hello.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print('Content-Type: text/html')
print()
print('<html><body><h2>Hello World!</h2></body></html>')
EOF
```

After that I can run it like this (note that `--directory` doesn't have effect for `--cgi` so I `cd` there):

```
cd app && python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

Then on my machine, I can `curl http://nas:8000/cgi-bin/hello.py`.

### Running on boot

You can run this automatically on boot via the task scheduler.

*Control Panel* → *Task Scheduler* → *Create* → *Triggered Task* → *User-defined script*. Fill these on *General* tab:

- Task: Python CGI
- User: admin
- Enabled: [x]

And *User-defined script* on *Task Settings* tab:

```
cd /var/services/homes/admin/app
python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

Then you can run it manually. It should also run on reboot.

### Permissions

If you want to run the task as `root`, make sure file permissions are correct from `root`'s point of view. In my case there's discrepancy by some reason.

```
$ ls -l app/cgi-bin/hello.py 
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 admin users 122 Nov 29 14:50 app/cgi-bin/hello.py
$ sudo ls -l app/cgi-bin/hello.py 
Password: 
-rwx--x--x+ 1 admin users 122 Nov 29 14:50 app/cgi-bin/hello.py
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a problem running the python script from a CLI, the issue is having the Apache server in Synology serve it up successfully.

Comment: My answer shows how to use Python built-in HTTP server to serve CGI scripts (which can be arbitrary executables, not just "Python scripts"). It can also serve static files, so you may not need another server (i.e. Apache) at all if it already covers your use case(s).

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you're showing, but it doesn't really pertain with getting Apache working to serve up python scripts, which was the original question posted.

Comment: this was exactly what i needed.  1000x would rather deal with python than apache.